# WebHook Issue in acumatica 23r2. It works fine Acumatica 23 R1

Tags: acumatica

I am using webhooks in Acumatica to send customer approval notifications, accept the responses, and update them in Acumatica.

The webhook link is sent to Acumatica through email notifications. By clicking the link, it brings up the custom page for customer approval. The routine works fine in Acumatica 23 R1 and is throwing an error while compiling the code given below.

```
    using PX.Data;
using PX.Data.Webhooks;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web;
using PX.Api.Webhooks.DAC;
using PX.Objects.SO;
using PX.SM;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Api.Services;
using INFOLicence;
namespace CustomWebhook
{
    public class ArtApprovalJobWebHooksServerHandler : IWebhookHandler
    {
        private NameValueCollection _queryParameters;

        private const string cLocationCD = "KeyValues";
        private const string cMode = "Mode";
        private const string cSendMode = "SendNotification";
        private const string cGetMode = "ReceiveResponse";

        async Task<IHttpActionResult> IWebhookHandler.ProcessRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            using (var scope = GetUserScope())
            {
                _queryParameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(request.RequestUri.Query);

                string htmlResponse = string.Empty;
                if (!_queryParameters.AllKeys.Contains(cLocationCD))
                    throw new Exception($"The {cLocationCD} Parameter was not specified in the Query String");
                var collectorID = _queryParameters[cLocationCD];
                try
                {
                    string sMode = string.Empty;
                    string values = collectorID;//Password.Decrypt(collectorID);
                    string[] arr = values.Split(new char[] { ';' });
                    string ordertype = arr[1];
                    string ordernbr = arr[2];
                    string locationcd = arr[4];
                    string setuptype = arr[0];
                    string jobcode = arr[3];
                    if (!_queryParameters.AllKeys.Contains(cMode))
                    {
                        //if nothing is specified for a mode Parameter we will assume GetSurvey
                        sMode = "SendNotification";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sMode = _queryParameters[cMode];
                    }

                    switch (sMode)
                    {
                        case cSendMode:
                            htmlResponse = GetSendAuth(cLocationCD, ordertype, ordernbr, locationcd, setuptype,jobcode); // invoking page from customer side for approval
                            break;
                        case cGetMode:
                            htmlResponse = SubmitApproval(collectorID, request); // Updating customer response
                            break;
                        default:
                            //htmlResponse = ReturnModeNotRecognized(sMode);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                catch (PXException e)
                {
                    throw e;
                }
                return new HtmlActionResult(htmlResponse);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not able to figureout the issue. Please let me know how to fix the issue

**Update**

I am generating the following URL for sending to customer

```
http://localhost/PrintShop23R2/Webhooks/Company/7fc9c9e3-05c9-4514-93d3-50a4beae9dcc?KeyValues=S;SO;SO007463;000001005;Location%201&Mode=SendNotification
```

The following URL throw following error

```
{
    "title": "An error has occurred.",
    "status": 500,
    "traceId": "80166d95-91d6-47fb-9b5a-b9224934962e"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Webhook was moved from `PX.Data.Webhooks` to `PX.Api.Webhooks` in 23R2.

Also, the handler is changed:

```
    public async Task HandleAsync(WebhookContext context, CancellationToken cancellation)
    {
        if (context.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Post.Method) 
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried the suggestion and it did not work.